# Find highest value in column using ANY or ALL

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and am currently learning and this is probably a fairly basic question:

I have 4 tables

> 1) Customer (customerName, street, customerCity)
>
> 2) Deposit (customerName, branchName, accountNumber, balance)
>
> 3) Loan (customerName, branchName, loanNumber, amount)
>
> 4) Branch (branchName, branchCity, assets)

Each table has some data inserted into it.

---

I have been asked to find the customerName with the highest deposit amount. (So I'm guessing I will be using just the Deposit table)?

However, here is the catch, the sheet I am learning from is requesting that I MUST use either ALL or ANY, I can't simply use the MAX function to achieve this.

---

How would I achieve this? I've tried query after query and simply can't find a way to get it to work (baring in mind that I've only been learning this for a week).

The things I've been trying have been along the lines of:

> SELECT customerName
>
> FROM Deposit
>
> WHERE balance > ALL;

---

The query should return 1 value, which would be the customerName with the highest balance value.

Thanks a lot for you help :)!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: I removed them again.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff , my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the customer(s) whose balance is greater than or equal to all balances in the table

so you just need to use `>=` instead of `>`

```
SELECT customerName
FROM   Deposit
WHERE  balance >= ALL (SELECT balance
                       FROM   Deposit);
```

Or you can use a correlated sub query and look for customers whose balances are greater than all other balance values.

```
SELECT customerName
FROM   Deposit d1
WHERE  balance > ALL (SELECT balance
                      FROM   Deposit d2
                      WHERE  d2.balance <> d1.balance);
```

In the event of ties both queries will return all customers with the highest amount.

Comment: Excellent, I tried the first method you suggested and it worked. It seems it was the >= I was missing - I knew it would be simple.. Thanks!